# How to access the Custom Protocol URL used to invoke the MACOS App which comprises of a single python file (from inside the python code)

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, pyobjc

I have written a small python file which I am packaging as a .app and installing on macos (latest version). The app is intended to be invoked using a custom protocol similar to "abc://efg/ijk/lmn". The python file employs pyobjc package and intends to use it to implement the business logic. I have option of using, only the Python language to implement my business logic because of legacy reasons.

I have to access the invoking custom URL "abc://efg/ijk/lmn" from inside the python code and parse the values. The "efg" "ijk" and "lmn" in the custom URL will vary and will be used to take some decisions further down the flow.

I have tried multiple things from whatever I could find from the internet but i am unable to access the custom url from with in the python code. The value of sys.argv come as below 
sys.argv = ['/Applications/XXXXXApp.app/Contents/MacOS/XXXXXApp', '-psn_0_4490312']

But on windows sys.argv[0] is populated with the custom url.

Will appreciate any directions.

Below code is what I have tried among many other variations of it.

`
from Cocoa import NSObject

mylogger = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/somefile.txt"), 'w+')

class apple_event_handler(NSObject):

```
 def applicationWillFinishLaunching_(self, notification):
    mylogger.write("Will finish ")


def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, notification):
    mylogger.write("Did Finish")


def handleAppleEvent_withReplyEvent_(self, event, reply_event):
    theURL = event.descriptorForKeyword_(fourCharToInt(b'----'))
    mylogger.write("********* Handler Invoked !!!  *********")
    mylogger.write("********* the URL = " + str(theURL))
    mylogger.write(*self.args)
```

aem = NSAppleEventManager.sharedAppleEventManager()

aeh = apple_event_handler.alloc().init()

aem.setEventHandler_andSelector_forEventClass_andEventID_(aeh, 
"handleAppleEvent:withReplyEvent:", 1, 1)
`

Comment: What do you use to package the application on macOS?

Comment: Another question: have you added the URL scheme to the Info.plist of the application bundle (the CFBundleURLTypes key in that plist)?

Comment: Thanks Ronald, I am using "productbuild", "pkgutil", "productsign" commands to build and sign the .app on macOS.

Comment: And Yes I have added the URL scheme thing to the info.plist. I am certain that the app is getting invoked when I type the custom URL in the browser's address bar, as from within the python file, I am creating one log file and writing the value of sys.argv which is coming as below.  sys.argv = ['/Applications/XXXXXApp.app/Contents/MacOS/XXXXXApp', '-psn_0_4580446']

Comment: Do you use a runloop? The URL is passed in through apple events and the Cocoa classes you use only process these when an event loop is active.  If you don't use an event loop: py2app has an argv-emulation mode that adds incoming file/URL open requests to sys.argv before running the actual script, see <https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/src/default/py2app/bootstrap/argv_emulation.py> for the implementation of that.

Comment: Hi Ronald, The code on the above said link works. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi @RonaldOussoren, Could you please provide some hints.